# Xamarin.android instead of Java

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm student and and my favorite language is  C#. 
However i must create my first  application for android and I have just found something about Xamarin. Does it make sense to use that instead of Java? Beacouse Java really doesn't match me. 
It's a  academic project, but also I'd like to deploy that to Google Play Store. 
In the Xamarin shop I found that I can develop my application on the free version, but propable i need Xamarin.Forms and buy INDIE license, isn't it?

Comment: If you're looking to develop just for Android, you may as well use the native framework. Xamarin's more if you want to push to multiple platforms in one go (well, sorta), but at the end of the day you still need to know how Android works.

Comment: One of the greatest aspects of Xamarin is that it enables you to write in C# a native code. I'm using it and it's a super framework, really easy to start writing a simple applications

Comment: If you are student you can get Indie version for free: http://xamarin.com/student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam, I will greatly encourage you to write your first app in native Android. Xamarin is an amazing tool set and you should keep tuned in to Xamarin but be rest assured that Xamarin or any other non native development tool is not for the beginners nor the faint of heart.

The reason I encourage you to get started with native Android is because of Documentation, Examples and Getting Unstuck. When you run into problem with native Android, either Google already have a sample project that addresses that issue with code example, or it has already been asked, debated and answered in StackOverflow.

One thing that will help you though is the complexity of your first project, if you choose a complex app you may never ship it. If you choose a moderate app, then the issue of having to know Java is essentially a mute point because the framework provides most of the plumbing code you need to accomplish most basic use cases. The remaining Java you will pick up as needed.

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

It dosnt matter if your develop with Xamarin or native Java. You will always have to know about the Android Framework. 
Futher you don't need to use Xamarin.Forms, you could also write the UI Part platform specific.

The need for Xamarin.Form is that you code your UI once and be able to deploy them to iOS, Android and WindowsPhone devices.